# How to Display a Specific Type of Object in Realm Swift?

Tags: swift, database, swiftui, realm, swiftui-list

I'm new to Realm and I'm having some trouble displaying the result as plain text. When I query from Realm(and filtering if necessary), I get the result with all key-value pairs.

The function I use to read the results:

```
func getData() {
let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1)
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    
let result = realm.objects(AllCard.self)
print(result)
}
```

}

The result I get in the console:

```
Optional(Results<AllCard> <0x7fd79dc0fed0> (
[0] AllCard {
    name = Chase Sapphire Reserve;
    bank = Chase
},
[1] AllCard {
    name = Citibank DoubleCash;
    bank = Citibank
}
```

))

So, for example, I want to display the corresponding "name" value as a Text(or as a list) in SwiftUI, how do I do it?
I've tried appending the results to an empty list and displaying it as a list from there, but I couldn't get it working...
This problem seems to be easy to solve, but at this point I'm brain-dead.
-Thanks!

Comment: Realm does not have key: value pairs. Realm has Realm Objects and objects have properties. Your code requests realm retrieve all AllCard objects from the database and store them in the `result` object. Check out the Realm Getting Started guide [Queries](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) for more info on Results. Is your question about actually working with SwiftUI or how to access an objects properties?

Comment: How to access an objects property. I actually found out a way: `@State private var allCardResult: Results<allCard> = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1)).objects(allCard.self)`

Comment: Treat the results like an array. Assuming you're interested in the first object in results,  `let card = results[0]` and then to get to the property `let bank = card.bank`

Comment: Now I'm having problems string interpolating NSPredicates while I filter out the result, sigh

Comment: I used `let card = results[0]` and I got back a fatal error: `Thread 1: "Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0)."`

Comment: That's correct. You have to populate the results first otherwise it will be nil. So you have to do this `let result = realm.objects(AllCard.self)` before trying to access the results. probably a good idea to test for nil before accessing it as well. Remember, treat it like an array.

Comment: thanks, I got it working, my results is already populated before though...

Comment: Well, your results can't be populated before this `let result = realm.objects(AllCard.self)` because that's what queries Realm for the data.